# LINQ to Entities Foreign key associations

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-entities, foreign-keys

I am new to asp.net, C# and sql and could use some guidance.. I am using the :below: db with the linq-to-entities framework. I need to associate a particular 'Ride' with a particular 'Vehicle' but am unsure exactly how to proceed. I have set a navigation property between the two objects but now need to let the vehicle hold a reference to a list of the rides it takes. Do I need a separate column in vehicle to hold this list of rides? Could someone please show me the syntax to accomplish this?

Here is the code I currently have, with comments at the two spots I need help:

```
private void setNewRide(Ride newRide, int carNum)
        {
            using (myEntities = new RamRideOpsEntities())
            {
                var assignedCar = (from car in myEntities.Vehicles
                                where (car.CarNum == carNum)
                                select car).FirstOrDefault();

                if (assignedCar != null && newRide != null)
                {                

                    Ride lastRide = assignedCar.Rides.LastOrDefault(); //HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO LOAD THE MOST RECENT 'RIDE' FOR THIS CAR, IS THIS CORRECT???

                    if (lastRide != null)
                    {
                        lastRide.Status = "Completed";
                        assignedCar.numRides = assignedCar.numRides + 1;
                        lastRide.TimeDroppedOff = DateTime.Now;
                        TimeSpan duration = (lastRide.TimeDroppedOff - lastRide.TimeDispatched).Value;

                        lastRide.ServiceTime = duration;
                        if (assignedCar.AvgRideTime == null)
                        {
                            assignedCar.AvgRideTime = duration;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            assignedCar.AvgRideTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(( ((TimeSpan)assignedCar.AvgRideTime).Seconds + duration.Seconds) / assignedCar.numRides);
                        }
                    }

                    assignedCar.Status = "EnRoute";
                    assignedCar.CurrPassengers = newRide.NumPatrons;
                    assignedCar.StartAdd = newRide.PickupAddress;
                    assignedCar.EndAdd = newRide.DropoffAddress;

                    //HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD THE 'newRide' OBJECT TO THE LIST OF RIDES IN THE 'assignedCar' ..SYNTAX???

                    newRide.TimeDispatched = DateTime.Now;
                    newRide.AssignedCar = carNum;
                    newRide.Status = "EnRoute";

                    myEntities.SaveChanges();
                    SelectCarUP.DataBind();
                    SelectCarUP.Update();                    
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: EDMX]

Comment: Unless EF is doing something clever I'm unaware of, the line you've commented as an issue is relying on a mythical natural ordering which does not exist (at least in the form most believe it to) within SQL Server.  The order of those Rides is based on which Page Sql server inserts the record, which is only deterministic if you know the space remaining on the page and inserted rows' exact size.  This is unlikely, so use an `OrderBy` clause.  Back to your original question, what is wrong with the line of code you commented?  An exception? Nothing returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For:

```
// HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO LOAD THE MOST RECENT 'RIDE' FOR THIS CAR, IS 
// THIS CORRECT???
Ride lastRide = assignedCar.Rides.LastOrDefault();
```

Use:

```
Ride lastRide = assignedCar.Rides
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.TimeDispatched)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

...and for:

```
// HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD THE 'newRide' OBJECT TO THE LIST OF RIDES 
// IN THE 'assignedCar' ..SYNTAX???
```

...your `Vehicle` entity has a `Rides` collection property already according to your model diagram, so you should just be able to say:

```
assignedCar.Rides.Add(newRide);
```

Finally - and purely as a matter of personal taste - instead of:

```
var assignedCar = (from car in myEntities.Vehicles
                   where (car.CarNum == carNum)
                   select car).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'd use:

```
var assignedCar = myEntities.Vehicles
    .FirstOrDefault(car => car.CarNum == carNum);
```

Comment: You all rock, thanks! Just one more question.. in response to the comment :above: about the indeterminate ordering... when i use 'assignedCar.Rides.Add(newRide)' is it indeed the case that the 'rides' will not remain in the order added as they would in an array? I will use the orderby clause anyway, but just in the interest of learning...

Comment: Ah, it looks like I still have one issue... When using the 'assignedCar.Rides.Add(newRide) statement, I get the following exception: "The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects." Any thoughts?

Comment: Strike that, figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: After you call the `.Add(newRide)` method, the object gets added to the collection. When you eventually call `SaveChanges()` on the `ObjectContext` it gets saved to the database. I don't think I understand it as well as @Smudge202 does, but I believe they're correct - the order those objects are retrieved in will not necessarily be the order in which they exist in the database, so if you need them in a particular order, use an `OrderBy()` call. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the following articles are good places to start:

1. [EF 4.1 Code First Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)
2. [Code First Relationships Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698). See Blog and Post entities, where Blog has a **one-to-many
   relationship** with Posts.